# users session and mysql_query

Tags: session

i'm trying to put user $_SESSION and mysql_query together, if you know what i mean, 
example: $_SESSION($dn)['account_type'] == 1 
is that posible to put $_SESSION and $dn together or is there other way to do this ?

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['username']) and ($_SESSION['username']==$dn['author'] or       $_SESSION($dn)['acc_type'] == 1)){ 
echo "test";
}
?>
```

Comment: It isn't clear what you are attempting. Is an array `$_SESSION['dn']` set? Is it `$_SESSION['dn']['acc_type']` you are looking for?

Comment: Also, please don't use `and/or`. Their [precedence](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) is slightly different from the more appropriate logical `&&` and `||`, and sooner or later this will cause you logic problems.

Comment: i'm using this in forum, and,or used for different users session, so if its current users post allowed him to edit this post, or if $_SESSION $account_type == 1/ allow user whom $account_type is 1